# w:vMerge from Word ML to rowspan in HTML

Tags: xml, xslt, wordml

we are converting Word File into XML using XSLT. How we can get the rowspan attribute in tables.

This is XSLT code to achieve this.

```
<xsl:template match="w:tc">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="w:tcPr/w:vMerge[@w:val='restart'] or w:tcPr[not(w:vMerge)]">
            <td>
                <xsl:if test="w:tcPr/w:gridSpan">
                    <xsl:attribute name="colspan" select="w:tcPr/w:gridSpan/@w:val"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="w:tcPr/w:vMerge[@w:val='restart']">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(parent::w:tr/following-sibling::w:tr[w:tc/w:tcPr/w:vMerge[not(@w:val)]])"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </td>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

However this code is counting all the rows. I need to limit the count to the next @w:val='restart'. Is this possible in XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XSLT 3.0, there is the `<<` comparison operator that tests whether a node is before another node (from 2.0), and you can bind the next `@w:val='restart'` with a *let*. I could imagine something along the lines of:

```
let $guard := parent::w:tr/following-sibling::w:tr[@w:val='restart'][1]
  (: Note: I probably got the above XPath wrong so it needs fine-tuning :)
return count(
  parent::w:tr/following-sibling::w:tr
    [. << $guard]
    [w:tc/w:tcPr/w:vMerge[not(@w:val)]]
)
```

Comment: We are using only opensource Saxon i.e. HE version. XSLT 3.0 is not part of HE